# FireDac ApplyUpdates Bug on FDTable with CachedUpdate

Tags: delphi, firedac, interbase

I develop and application on Delphi 5 with BDE and never got any reclaim till I update to Delphi XE 10 I change my data Engine From BDE to Firedac. program is simple POS app make invoices , Invoice Table with Items table master-details. from time to time miss some invoices not specific but around 11 each 1000.

I start looking, checking and changing , i add Transaction component.. test same result later adding SchemaAdapter same result Till i figure out what is the problem

if the data Server running an statement in the same time what to run a different statement from another client on the same table here you can found the big bug on FireDac that the 2th client will appear that the data saved but in fact nothing saved

otherwise same scenario on BDE the result completely different the 2th client raise an error with message "Dead ... SQL " at least know that the data not saved

Hope some test that too , heavy SQL statement run it on the Server and try to insert on the table in CachUpdate -> and applyUpdate and will see the result

All Above use Interbase Database

Comment: Sorry, to get help with this, you will need to show the code you are using, preferably by adding an [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your q.  Without seeing what you are doing, readers cannot comment sensibly on what might be wrong.  It is rather unlikely that you have found a bug in FireDAC since it + Interbase should be far more robust than a BDE-based application; more likely it is an error in your code.

Comment: Btw, IIRC, the main reason for the interest in the BDE era in Cached Updates was the difficulty of getting updateable result sets from servers.  That problem has long since been side-stepped by DB-access libraries which retrieve data using read-only Sql queries and automatically generate UPDATE statements to update the data on the server, e.g. TClientDataSet+TDataSetProvider and FireDAC.  You may therefore very well find that you do not need to use Cached Updates with FireDAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue resolved in Delphi 10.3 , the Firedac engine work fine now